# notify url = wordpress path

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

i'm having an issue using wordpress pathing when i use paypal button. the paypal button is working if the form code is not encypted but when i encrypt it does not work

sample code

without encryption

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url');?>/myfile.php">
```

with encryption

```
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7----- blahblah -----END PKCS7-----
```

what can i do in order for my notify url work?

Answer (score 0):

The URL cannot be encrypted.
see the [PayPal IPN Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/). The request to your notification URL will contain some information which you can send back to a PayPal server to confirm to confirm for yourself that it was really sent by PayPal, and to let PayPal know that you received the notification.